# Abstract data type constructor can be accidentally bypassed?

Tags: go, abstract-data-type

I'm trying to make an abstract data type representing a positive number:

```
package m

type positiveNum int

func MakePositiveNum(i int) positiveNum {
    if i < 1 { panic("non positive number") }
    return positiveNum(i)
}

// some function that expects a positive number
func UsePositiveNum(s positiveNum) {}
```

Here are some example uses:

```
package main
import "m"
func main() {
    pn := m.MakePositiveNum(123)
    //i := 1; m.UsePositiveNum(i) // fails as expected because
                                  // int is passed instead of positiveNum
    //useInt(pn) // fails because trying to pass positiveNum instead of int
    //pn = m.positiveNum(0) // fails as expected because the type is private
    m.UsePositiveNum(pn)
}

func UseInt(int) {}
```

If you replace `m.UsePositiveNum(pn)` with `m.UsePositiveNum(0)`, it still compiles, bypassing the positive number typecheck. Why?

Comment: Because the zero value of `int` .. and therefore `positiveNum` .. is 0.

Comment: If it's unsafe for people to create your type via a literal, don't export your type at all, only an interface it satisfies; `compress/bzip2` does something like this by returning an `io.Reader`. Otherwise, Go style is open to exposing data, unlike C++ etc.; standard library types like `http.Server` do it. Trying to follow C++ rules in Go won't go well, as you see. Go is effectively a [style](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments) and [set of conventions](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), not only a language, so if you want to learn it, learn the whole thing.

Comment: It isn't exported. line 3: `type positiveNum int`. Lowercase means not exported, right?

Comment: Ah, noted, I misinterp'd your question and it's a more interesting one than I thought (and James and Peter's answers actually respond to your question, unlike my comment). Still generally true that one way to seal your type off from access that isn't through your functions is to follow `compress/bzip2`'s example and return an interface instead of whatever you're representing the type as internally. peterSO's way looks good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that `0` is an [*untyped constant*](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants).  Such constants are covered by [this rule about assignability](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability):

> A value `x` is assignable to a variable of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") in any of these cases:
>
> - ...
> - `x` is an untyped constant representable by a value of type `T`.

Since `positiveNum`'s underlying type is `int`, which can represent `0`, the conversion happens without error.

@peterSO's answer provides a way to avoid this implicit conversion, since there is no implicit conversion from an integer constant to a struct.  Note that it won't protect against a malicious user creating a value like `positive.Positive{0}`, but that is usually not a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it compiles. There is nothing that prevents a value of type `positiveNum` to be zero or less. The only *runtime* check you have is in `MakePositiveNum`, which you never call when you do the following:

```
m.UsePositiveNum(0)
```

Every function/method that receives a value of type `positiveNum` must do the validation, not only `MakePositiveNum` if you want to be sure. Else you have to assume the developer will always use `MakePositiveNum` to create the value.

You can find something similar in the standard library with [`image.Rectangle`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/#Rectangle). Many of it´s methods assume that Min.X <= Max.X and Min.Y <= Max.Y, but there is no actual validation, only the guarantee that:

> A rectangle's methods always return well-formed outputs for well-formed inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for something like this:

ADT:

```
package positive

type Positive struct{ i uint64 }

func New(i int) Positive {
    if i < 1 {
        panic("not a positive number")
    }
    return Positive{i: uint64(i)}
}

func Function(p Positive) Positive { return p }

func (p Positive) Method() Positive { return p }

func (p Positive) Integer() uint64 { return p.i }
```

Usage:

```
package main

import "positive"

func main() {
    pn := positive.New(123)
    i := 1; positive.Function(i) // fails
    UseInt(pn) // fails
    pn = positive.Positive(0) // fails
    positive.Function(pn)
    positive.Function(0) // fails
}

func UseInt(int) {}
```